# Right-click and select a context menu option with Ruby in Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, contextmenu

How could I tell Ruby to right-click a file in a Windows folder and select an option from the context menu in a simple script?

Comment: The native shellexecute API can run certain verbs, many custom right click options map back to a set of arguments & a runnable program, what are you trying to do?

Comment: The [Pickaxe Windows Support chapter](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/lib_windows.html) may be useful in a _really general_ way, but depending on what you're trying to achieve there may be a simpler way.

Comment: I'm trying to select the "Send To -> Desktop" option in the Windows 7 context menu.

Comment: Then you probably just need to use the [win32utils](http://win32utils.rubyforge.org/) to create a shortcut and save it on the Desktop.

Comment: Any ideas on how I could use Ruby to use the same context menu, but to "Send To - Documents" or "Send To -> Amazon Cloud Drive"?

Comment: https://github.com/stevenheidel/autoit-ruby

Answer (score 3):

Using *win32utils* you can avoid using API calls to send links to Desktop:

```
require 'win32/shortcut'
require 'win32/dir'
include Win32

Shortcut.new(Dir::DESKTOP + '\shortcut.lnk') do |s|
  s.path = "c:\\path\\to\\something.exe"
  s.window_style = Shortcut::SHOWNORMAL
  s.description = "My shortcut to something"
end
```

You'll need the `win32-shortcut` and `win32-dir` gems; you'll also need to determine the file path to give to `Shortcut#path`. This is usually easily done using the `Dir#each`, passing it the directory you're interested in, and doing some kind of control on the directory elements you iterate upon.

Comment: Great answer for the creating a Shortcut issue (thanks!, vote up), but do you have any suggestions about how I could select other options within the Windows context (right-click) menu? (See my reply to your comment above.)

Comment: While I'm not aware of any way to _click_ on contextual menu items, there are plenty of ways to mimic the same behavior. For example, you could obtain the `Dir::COMMON_DOCUMENTS` using the `win32-dir` shortcut, then copy the file here using [`FileUtils::cp`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp).